# How to gain admin access on windows

Tags: windows, privilege-escalation

I've been trying to get admin on my own pc for probably like 4 years now and I still can't find anything. I tried to do the utilman swap with cmd but then literally my av blocked it and then it deleted my utilman.

I've also tried running steam as admin by getting my parents to do that and adding cmd as a game but still no admin.

Comment: We are not a "how to hack" site.

Comment: Create a live Linux system, with this, you can literally do anything with your Windows file system

Comment: sounds like it's your parents' PC, not yours?